# Ionic ios app not emulating to ios simulator through cli commands

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am starting to create new app with latest ionic version.

I got the following info through **ionic info** command

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.13.7
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

I just followed the following steps

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic serve
```

when i run ionic serve i get the web page opened automatically.

and then i have added the ios developer account to the xcode

```
xcode-select --install
npm install -g ios-sim
brew install ios-deploy
ionic cordova prepare ios
ionic cordova run ios -l --external
```

so finally when i run the cli command. I get the simulator opened automatically and some popup verifying myapp.app and close after few seconds after that app not installed in simulator.

It works when I run manually from xcode.

Please help me to get the "ionic cordova run ios -l --external" command run successfully.
[image: terminal screenshot with simulator]

When i run cordova in the terminal i get the following error but cordova is installed globally using the sudo command and cordova folder is exist in the npm modules.

cordova

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:236
>       throw err
>       ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/Users/soundhar/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-cordova.json.2409298856'
>       at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
>       at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:212:13)
>       at Conf.set store [as store] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/index.js:142:19)
>       at new Conf (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/conf/index.js:44:14)
>       at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:40:35)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:26:15)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14) {   errno: -13,   syscall: 'open',   code: 'EACCES',   path:
>   '/Users/soundhar/Library/Preferences/insight-nodejs/insight-cordova.json.2409298856'
>   }

Thanks for all

Comment: I am not sure but try `ionic cordova run ios --emulator`  this command. let me know.

Comment: ionic cordova emulate ios

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this two commands:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Comment: I added the commands and then i tried to run with the verbose command i get the following result

Comment: Error: The platform "–" does not appear to have been added to this project.
    at Object.getPlatformApi

Comment: (/Users/soundhar/Projects/ionic/practice/appOne/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:46:15)
    at /Users/soundhar/Projects/ionic/practice/appOne/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:52:38
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/soundhar/Projects/ionic/practice/appOne/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:50:47
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
  cordova build ios – --verbose exited with exit code 1

Comment: Ok. I think i found it. Dont run: ionic cordova prepare ios but run ionic cordova platform add ios as describe on ionic cli documentation

Comment: when i run the **ionic cordova platform add ios** i am getting Platform ios already exists. i will try to uninstall cordova and re install as you said. lets see

Comment: still same after re install the cordova. same error app not installed into simulator

Comment: did you run add ios command? you can share your git repo with me? parrycima is my username

Comment: thanks for your kind help. i tried everything nothing works. so, i formatted the hard disk and start fresh. it works now. i repeated same things. now its installing in the simulator automatically